# jQuery sortable table cells cancel

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, html-table, jquery-ui-sortable

I have problem with sortable `<TD>`'s.

```
$("table tbody").sortable({
   handle: "td[tyhi='0']",
   cancel: "td[tyhi='1']"
});
```

Code above is not working...
How to exclude a `<TD>` with attribute `tyhi="1"`?

http://jsfiddle.net/tiitremmel/sFLFb/

Comment: The code you have works: http://jsfiddle.net/sFLFb/1/

Comment: yes it works, but i need it so that you can't put first or second to last position. tyhi="1" have to be always last.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I need it so that you can't put first or second to last position. `tyhi="1"` have to be always last

In that case, you will need to put the sortable/non-sortable elements within different containing elements. In you example with a table, putting the `td` elements which must appear last in a `tfoot` would be most semantic:

```
<table>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td tyhi="0">first</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td tyhi="0">second</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
    <tfoot>
        <tr>
            <td tyhi="1">third</td>
        </tr>
    </tfoot>
</table>
```

jQuery

```
$("table tbody").sortable({
   handle: "td"
});
```

[**Example fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/sFLFb/3/)

Comment: In my case - your solution were the best. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

you want to sort rows, not cells, so html should look like this:

```html
<table>
<tbody>
    <tr tyhi="0">
        <td>first</td>
    </tr>
    <tr tyhi="0">
        <td>second</td>
    </tr>
    <tr tyhi="1">
        <td>third</td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

​
And javascript:

```js
$("table tbody").sortable({
   items: "tr:not(tr[tyhi='1'])"
}).disableSelection();
```